# are there any bugs about 'dust js recursion'?

Tags: javascript, recursion

[Dust js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) web gives us some examples. One of them is recursion.

When I change the 'name' of the json in the 3rd section and the 'name' in 1st section to other string like 'node', the output is wrong! What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
{node}{~n}{#kids}{>recursion:./}{/kids}

{
  "node": "1",
  "kids": [{
    "node": "1.1",
    "kids": [{
      "node": "1.1.1"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because "recursion" is a template loaded in the dust context.

In dust you can load other templates by name: So when he writes this:

```
{>recursion:./}
```

He is loading a template called recursion. you can find it in the examples files.

this is the recursion template:

```
{
name:     "recursion",
source:   "{name}{~n}{#kids}{>recursion:./}{/kids}",
context:  {
            name: '1',
            kids: [
              {
                name: '1.1',
                kids: [
                  {name: '1.1.1'}
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
expected: "1\n1.1\n1.1.1\n"
}
```

You should create another template with the node fields, load it in the dust context and then just use it.